# Feasibility of a basic physical-layer wireless communications system

Tags: integrated-circuit, filter, communication, wireless, design

We would like to make simple, cheap comms chips that provide a pool of users one real or complex sample per user per communication time slot. Its footprint needs to be similar to a BLE chip (~1"x1", <15g able to be powered for a long time by a 3.7V 200mAh battery).

The most we hope for is for the system to be capable of send/receive on the order of tens of bits per second.

Here is a rough idea (I have no hardware knowledge so this might be bogus)

> \$N\approx 3\$ devices are equipped with IR beamers/receivers, and each is designated an offset \$f_n\$ from the carrier frequency \$f\$.
>
> Per communication frame:
>
> - For device \$n\$ to transmit, a microcontroller's PWM with \$P_n\%\$ uptime is turned on and off with (local) frequency \$f+f_n\$ to power an IR light.
> - For device \$n\$ to receive, it cross-correlates the IR receiver's signal with a bank of frequency windows centered at \$\{f+f_k:k\neq n\}\$. The cross-correlation magnitudes are averaged over a short duration and read by an ADC for processing.

All the higher-level stuff would be handled by the users, which each have a microcontroller with specs on the order of a fast Arduino.

---

As far as I know, here are the miracles that have to happen for this to be feasible:

- The components to amplify and filter the receive signal must exist and be tiny, cheap and low-power.
- The oscillators on the PWMs have to be consistent enough with each other that correlation with window functions is enough to isolate each user's signal (so we avoid heavier, more complicated things like DSPs or PLLs)
- The PWMs need to have well-separated frequency response.
- (would be nice) The IR blasters are powerful enough that the channel statistics are approximately Gaussian (when really they are Rayleigh)

---

Are any of these showstoppers, or is there a reasonable chance of success? Are there cheap off-the-shelf chips that do this?

In particular, is there a cheap, small (comparable to a to220) IC that will do the filtering/correlation? What is it called?

Comment: *The crystals on the microcontrollers* A microcontroller is made on a Silicon crystal, but that is not what you mean. You mean that the Crystal oscillators are .... and there you've lost me. You appear to think in ultra complex solutions which are probably not needed.

Comment: You're right, that made no sense. I meant the oscillators that the PWMs are driven by.

Comment: Yes there are cheap OTS parts that will do this, they are found in TV remotes, use modulated IR, need mW levels of power, are the size of pin heads, cost a pittance and most importantly, *already have Arduino libraries*. The most important part absent from your question is *"Why do you want to roll your own?"* If it's as a learning exercise, that's totally fine, but if you're looking to develop a solution as a marketable product or as part of a practical project, I'd strongly recommend using an OTS IR system like [this one](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/ir-communication)

Comment: OTS systems would be great, I am just ignorant of them. The reason we were trying to design our own is because the types of things we want to demo with this system are lower level than just serial data-in/data-out. 
\$\begin{align}\phantom{asdf}\\ \phantom{gh}\end{align}\$
the ultimate goal is to demo esoteric networking protocols that do adaptive stuff like channel estimation and on-the-fly constellation switching.

Answer (score 2):

At a user group size of ~3 , you can safely just ignore the fact that data that you send might interfere. If you're not transmitting ultimatively slow, the likelyhood of two packets colliding is pretty small.

Your system hence is a classical candidate for simple [Aloha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet), i.e. everyone just transmits when they have data to transmit. If there was a collision, just retransmit (typically, you wait a *random* amount of time before retransmitting, to avoid colliding right again).

You should probably implement a message-acknowledge scheme, i.e. the station that the message was meant for should reply with a "OK, got it". If you get that, everything is OK. If you don't (within a certain time frame), retransmit.

Advantage of that: all the hardware you need is simply one IR transmitter/receiver system. The classical TV remote systems will work reasonably well enough.

Addressing is simply done by setting a specific address field in the custom data format you're using.

---

I definitely don't want to dismiss you FDMA system, though. But: you're overthinking things. What you'd effectively do is just multiply your transmit signal with a sine. You can do that *within* any modern MCU. No need for fancy external components. However, for this application, you could do even simpler: Go for CDMA (ha, giving you loads of stuff to google) to address each receiver differently – that is, multiply the bits you want to transmit with a sequence of symbols that is unique to each receiver, and whose cross-correlation with other receiver's sequences is as small as possible. The receivers just correlate with their own sequence – and hence get back the original bits.

Comment: Re CDMA approaches, this paper may be of interest: ["Analysis of Indoor Wireless Infrared Optical CDMA LAN Using Prime 
Codes "](http://www.wseas.org/multimedia/journals/communications/2012/55-271.pdf).